# Subversion command line commit does nothing

Tags: svn

When I run:

```
svn commit -m "some message" myFile.txt
```

in the DOS shell, it gives me an empty line as the result. There's no error message, etc. And the file is not committed.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file really was modified (i.e., you didn't just forget to save your changes), then you should check the [conditions which make a file appear as modified](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#detectmodification) for Subversion:

1. has the 'last modification' date and/or the file size changed?
2. if not: file is not modified
3. if yes: compare file content with the BASE file
4. stop at the first byte that differs, mark the file as modified
5. if no byte differs regarding to BASE, mark the file as not-modified

Answer (score 8):

Did you svn add myFile.txt first?

You can only commit changes to files that are added to svn.

Comment: Wouldn't it say that myFile.txt is not under version control, though?

Answer (score 7):

most likely there are no changes. Try `svn status`

Comment: That means there are no changes.

Comment: But I can guarantee there are changes, I modified the file the second before.

What could cause this?

Comment: I know it seems obvious, but did you edit the correct copy of the file?  Also try svn diff myFile.txt.  My guess is that will return nothing too.

Comment: Did you save the file? I know, it sounds stupid, but I sometimes find myself commiting things without saving them before.

Comment: if `svn diff filename` returns nothing, then there are no changes from what is in the repository.

Comment: What's interesting is that I changed the file again a few minutes later and it works.

All of a sudden it works, then it doesn't again. I wait some time, re-change teh file, and voila it works...

Comment: A favourite of mine is trying to commit a `.cpp` file when I only modified the `.hpp`file etc. Was convinced I had the right file...

Answer (score 3):

Do "svn st myFile.txt". If the first column has a ? in it, then the file isn't under source control and you need to "svn add myFile.txt". If the first column is blank, then there aren't any changes to commit. If the first column is something else, then "svn help st" will give you the meaning of the other possible flags.

Answer (score 0):

In my expirience, the `.php` file I was working on was a **soft link** of an original in some another location. Hence, despite the fact that original file was changing the soft link was staying the same. I have swapped the original file with the link and the other way around and `Commit`, `Status` and `Update` commands started to pick up the changes.

You can distinguish between the original file and the soft copy in **Linux** by the arrow shape and the location of an origina on front of it in the following format when you do `ls -la`:

```
myTestfile.xxx -> /var/www/html/myTestOriginalfile.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In mine case it was a versioned directory rename in an external directory in an external directory.
I have had workaround this through the commit run directly on the last external directory.
I still don't know what did causing it and could not reproduce it.